# Concatenate string using SSIS expression builder

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to concatenate some strings using expression builder within SSIS depending on a variable being null or not but get the following error message

`"String1" + ISNULL( @[User::ReservingAnalysisClassCodes]) ? "String2" : "String3"`

[image: Error Message]

Comment: `? :` has the [lowest possible precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/integration-services/expressions/operator-precedence-and-associativity), so `+` binds tighter. Parenthesize your expression properly.

Comment: Translated: you need to surround the entire expression after the `+` with parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

Per Nick from the comments, this should work:

```
"String1" + (ISNULL( @[User::ReservingAnalysisClassCodes]) ? "String2" : "String3")
```

SSIS is trying to concatenate "String1" + ISNULL( @[User::ReservingAnalysisClassCodes] which is why it's throwing an error.